# How to efficiently get many foreign entries(many to one entries) for one entity but not using group_concat?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables in SQL, properties and photos(String filepath). What I want to do is get all the photos per property as such and send it to the front end so that it can iterate through them and display it all.

```
Property--------hasAttribute--------Attribute Photo
               P1 | A1
               P1 | A2
               P1 | A3
               P2 | A1
               P2 | A2
               P3 | A2
               P3 | A3
```

Something like this

```
P1 | A1 | A2 | A3          P1 | A1, A2, A3
P2 | A1 | A2         or    P2 | A1, A2
P3 | A2 | A3               P3 | A2, A3
```

However I figured that you can group them and get AS A SINGLE STRING with group_concat. But that means the FE would have to regex the String which would be bad. So the group_concat doesn't work I think?

How would you return the query? Not entirely sure what is performant.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact `GROUP_CONCAT()` can easily generate the second output version:

```sql
SELECT property, GROUP_CONCAT(attribute ORDER BY attribute) AS attrs
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY property;
```

Comment: Hi Tim! thank you for commenting!

But I don't think this works as it will return a string and the front end will still have to regex the string to get each file path. 

Maybe, is it possible for it to return a json object that's like

{ 
   "name" : "Property 1",
   "images" : {
      "Images1", "Images2"
    },
   "name" : "Property 2",
   "images" : {
      "Images3", "Images4"
    },
}

but idk, is this possible or even optimal?

Comment: From your UI you should just do a simple select without aggregation and then process the data in your presentation layer.

Comment: Ohhh. I see, okay okay. So lets say theres a DB:sql, BE: springboot, FE:reactjs, the optimal way you recommend is to do simple queries to the DB and then the processing happens in the FE? Should this be the case for all the queries? Does that mean, it is less expensive to manipulate data on the FE than the DB?

Comment: The bandwidth you need to send the result set across either way is the same.  Handling presentation in the UI is the standard approach.